# how to add image to html file which is created using file.create method

Tags: c#

i am creating html file by using below code

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Attachments/test.html");

// Delete the file if it exists.
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    File.Delete(path);
}

// Create the file.
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path, 1024))
{
    byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("<html><body><div>Test</div></body><html>");

    // Add some information to the file.
    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
}
```

I want to add a image to this html file...
how to add image to this html file.

Comment: What did you try and where did you fail? Did you add a image to a HTML file using a HTML editor to see what you're expected to do? Did you do a basic google search for "HTML Image"?

Answer (score 2):

```
 byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("<html><body><div>Test</div><img src='image.png' alt='your added image'/></body><html>");
```

Comment: And, OP, you should of course make sure that the image resource the HTML refers to is actually provided when requested from the server/tool. It can be generated on the fly, naturally when requested. But not embedded in the HTML, only the URI to it.